# Physics of $N$ linked pendulums connected on two sides

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass

I was looking for information on how a series of pendulums linked together (not coupled but the bob of one pendulum connected to the pivot of another like in a double pendulum) would act when walked across like a bridge, connected on two sides but with some slack.

Just like the bridge in this game, hill climb:

[image]

The main reason I couldn’t find information about it was due to me not knowing what to call it.

Clarification:
When force is applied to a point on this series of linkages, how would its pose be calculated. The angle from each pendulum to the next would suffice.

Comment: *not coupled but the bob of one pendulum connected to the pivot of another like in a double pendulum* A double pendulum **is** coupled, so I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how it would act"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was taught that coupled meant two side by side pendulums connected by a beam, where the 2 pendulums are fixed at pivot points.

Comment: @Samuel by how it would act I guess I mean how would it’s pose be calculated based on where force is applied.

Comment: You have a serial chain of linkages that are connected together. Modeling such a system is rather complex. Simplifications can be made by adding the weights on the nodes and connecting the nodes with massless links.

Comment: @SaveerJain Coupled means that the dynamics of the two objects depend on each other (e.g., the position & velocity of one directly impacts the position & velocity of the other and vice versa).

Comment: Are you looking for resources to build a simulation? I would call this an articulated chain of bodies. Maybe call it a serial chain of linkages. The simulation would be complex to do because it forms a closed loop with the ground.